# What is the difference between an ObjC delegate and a C# delegate?

Tags: c#, objective-c, delegates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Delegates in objective c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4449382/delegates-in-objective-c)

ObjC and C# appear to attribute different meanings to the term 'delegate'

Could somebody clarify?

What is the difference between an ObjC delegate and a C# delegate?