# What does setting of delegate mean?

Tags: ios, delegates

Like in a sample code for XML parsing I encountered a comment:

```
NSXMLParser *xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];

//Initialize the delegate.
XMLParser *parser = [[XMLParser alloc] initXMLParser];

//Set delegate
[xmlParser setDelegate:parser];
```

Can somebody tell me the difference between protocol's delegate method and delegate in general?

Comment: The delegate is just another class that does its job.

Comment: You might be interested in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4449382/141081)

Comment: don't quite understand the question ... it is using a delegation pattern ... one of the frequently used patterns in iOS development. What do you mean by "protocol's delegate method" ?

Comment: @Yoeri : "protocol's delegate method" like for UITableView, protocol UITableViewDataSource has "numberOfRowsInSection" delegate method that is necessary to implement and called automatically by compiler in order to form a table. I am just aware about that DELEGATE. What does setting of delegate mean here?

Comment: I am aware of that ... it does just the same as the UITableView delegate. XMLParser implements a protocol called from the NSXmlParser. If you'd implement the protocol yourself, you could pass in your own object as delegate and provide an own implementation for the parser methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A protocol is like an interface. If you come from JAVA or C# you have already seen this in action. It's just a list of methods without implementation. A class can (or not) conforms to a specific protocol. A class has to implement methods that are marked as required. Those that are optionals could not be implemented.

Delegation, instead, is a pattern that creates a relationships between two different objects. One of them, say A, is assisted by the second, say B. In other words, B does something for A.

The relationships between the two is that delegate methods (for a specific class) are listed in protocols. Here the term delegate protocol.

Why delegation is important? At some point of your application lifecyle, if a class send a message to its delegate (this it is not nil) and it has implemented a specific method (it can respond to that selector), the message is received by its delegate. At this point the control is captured by the delegate that performs some calculation and maybe can return some result.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

the idea of delegation is simply like when you have some operation taking place and when something is done with it, or needs to notify another object to make an operation or get data from it asks the delegate. like for example:
the table view, it needs to get the list from the data source and tell someone when an object is selected, thats where you set the datasource and delegate which are objects the tableview will call methods on. defined in the protocol that they correspondingly implement.
(like talk to this delegate when u need something within that protocol)

I hope this informal explanation helps you out

for more (proper) info on delegates check: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern

Answer (score 1):

Generally, its is the object that "does the job".

In the case of NSXMLParser, when you create the parser, you set an object to be its delegate, that means that this object needs to implement the NSXMLParsedDelegate methods.

For example:

```
- (void) parseData:(NSData*) xmlResponse;

- (void)parserDidStartDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser;

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser parseErrorOccurred:(NSError *)parseError;

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict;

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName;

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string;

- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser;
```